# Configuring Multiple Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I have the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SamlConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        @Value("${enable_csrf}")
        private Boolean enableCsrf;

        @Autowired
        private SamlUserService samlUserService;

        public SamlWebSecurityConfig() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/sso").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .apply(saml())
                    .userDetailsService(samlUserService)
                    .serviceProvider()
                    .keyStore()
                    .storeFilePath("path")
                    .password("password")
                    .keyname("alias")
                    .keyPassword("password")
                    .and()
                    .protocol("https")
                    .hostname(String.format("%s:%s","localhost", "8080"))
                    .basePath("/")
                    .and()
                    .identityProvider()
                    .metadataFilePath("metadata");
            if (!enableCsrf) {
                http.csrf().disable();
            }
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class BasicConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        public BasicWebSecurityConfig() {
            super();
        }
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/basic").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            if (!enableCsrf) {
                http.csrf().disable();
            }
        }
    }
```

This works for the SAML, but the basic login returns an error: *403 forbidden*.

I modified the `BasicConfig` with this, and SAML doesn't work anymore but basic authentication works. All the endpoints are for both SAML and basic authentication, just different login page.

```java
public static class BasicConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        public BasicWebSecurityConfig() {
            super();
        }
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/basic").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            if (!enableCsrf) {
                http.csrf().disable();
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reasons sometimes it works, sometimes not. I also tried to modify the `@Order` and still not working.

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Security, there are two things that are alike but do things completely differently, `requestMatchers().antMatchers()` and `authorizeRequests().antMatchers()`.

The `requestMatchers` tells `HttpSecurity` to only invoke the `SecurityFilterChain` if the provided `RequestMatcher` was matched.

The `authorizeRequests` allows restricting access based upon the `HttpServletRequest` using `RequestMatcher` implementations.

In your case, you have two `SecurityFilterChain`s. But only the one with the highest priority is being invoked, this happens because you did not give any `requestMatchers` to it, therefore it will match every request. And only one `SecurityFilterChain` is called per request, thus it will not invoke the next one.

So, you should inform the `requestMatchers` for your configurations, like so:

```java
http
        .requestMatchers((requests) -> requests
                .antMatchers("/secure/sso", "/saml/**")
        )
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/secure/sso").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ...
```

```java
http
         .requestMatchers((requests) -> requests
                .antMatchers("/secure/basic", "/**")
         )
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/secure/basic").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, 500 - Internal Server Error.  I added .requestMatchers().antMatchers("...","....").and().authorizeRequests()......

Comment: Increase your log level to trace and see the stacktrace

Comment: http.requestMatchers is a private method 